# Do yellowing grape leaves indicate a serious problem?

Tags: grape-vine

I planted the vine in early Spring.  It seemed to grow quite well for the first few months.  However, over the last several weeks some of the older leaves have begun to yellow.

[image: First image of grape vine]

[image]

(For what it's worth I have no experience with grapes.)

Answer (score 4):

You should fertilize them. If it will not become much more severe, just do it this winter, else you can use additionally some leaf (liquid) fertilizer.

It is a frequent problem on new plants, especially if there were in past other plants/herbs.

Answer (score 2):

I have a few grape vines and this is normal. As we approach the fall/winter season, the levels start drying up and wither. All that will be left is the stem. You should train the vine and prune off the excess branches so when new leaves sprout next spring, the stronger branches will develop the leaves and fruit.